# .draggable() is not cooperating with Firefox's flex box

Tags: jquery

I built a simple jsfiddle to demonstrate my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/9MD43/

Resizing the box on Chrome keeps the box green, which is what I want. Attempting to resize the box on Firefox causes the box to turn red, because the flex box shrinks to nothing. Internet Explorer 10 behaves like Chrome does and keeps the box green (not shown in this example).

The problem can be alleviated by removing the .draggable command from the script:

```
$("#outer").resizable().draggable(); // <-- removing .draggable() will keep the box green in Firefox after resizing
```

The markup is very simple, nothing fancy:

```
<div id="outer">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="list">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

"#outer" is the flex box, and "#content" has a flex of 1.

"#content" is positioned with relative, and "#list" is positioned absolutely within it. In the full version of my app, I add items dynamically to the "#list" div and have overflow: scroll applied, which is why the CSS seems unusual for this simple example.

Is this a bug in jquery's .draggable and/or Firefox, and is there a clean workaround for this problem?

[edit] A much simpler example: http://jsfiddle.net/LXmuL/

Resizing the box collapes the flex on Firefox, but not on Chrome. This can be observed with the background color of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bug.

jquery adds absolute positioning to the draggable element. Firefox has a long-standing bug with flex boxes and absolute positioning: **https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=579776**. Indeed, setting the position of the outer box to absolute is sufficient to collapse the flex box in my example.